# How to getting latest partition data from hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop-streaming, hive-partitions

I need to fetch all records from a table in hive which is having latest partitions. The table is partitioned by `date,year,month` eg  `(date=25,year=2020,month=3)`, likewise there will be many partitions.

The partitions are not static and it will be changing frequently. I am trying to handle of getting the latest partition in the query.
Can anybody help me to write the query?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * 
  from your_table t
 where concat_ws('-',t.year,t.month,t.date) in (select max(concat_ws('-',s.year,s.month,s.date)) from your_table s)
```

Also read these related answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675908/2700344

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41952357/2700344

Comment: @AnushaRadhakrishnan fixed. Add table aliases

Comment: the fields year,month ,date are in int datatype hence concat_ws is not working

Comment: @AnushaRadhakrishnan okay, use cast(year as string), lpad(month,2,0) lpad(date ,2,0)