# How to fetch latest date from a hive table partitioned on date column?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

eg. If my date column is load_date, using max(load_date) operator will scan every data file in hive making it a costly operation. Instead is there any optimal way to get the latest load_date from the table.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60830341/2700344

Answer (score 3):

Just thinking out of Hive,Assuming that you've configured mysql for your metastore instead of derby and the partition column load_date.

**Suggestion 1:** This query gives you all partition name. Do sub string (day=2020-05-24) and take date part out of it and cast it to date and then get the max value.

```
mysql> select PART_NAME FROM PARTITIONS WHERE TBL_ID=(SELECT TBL_ID FROM TBLS WHERE TBL_NAME='PARTITIONED_TABLE');
```

**Suggestion 2:** If you dont have mysql or access issue, then get the partition list out using below command and write a shell script which reads this file and give the max load_date.

```
$hive -e 'show partitions table;' > partitions.txt
```

**Suggestion 3**: In Hive, the way is, just to avoid full table scan. Here "-3" is variable, change it to last successful day load if you know it.

```
select max(load_date) from db.table_name
where load_date>date_add(current_date,-3)
```

Note: Not sure how you want to consume the output of max(load_date), you can always store the value in hive table and use in your query.

Answer (score 0):

The only way in Hive to check max date is using **max** aggregation function. In your case its `max(load_date)`.

Not only Hive, in any relational database, this is the approach to find the latest date. If required in your design you can have a metadata table, where it records the statistics of each file loaded in hive, this helps you to get the latest record